# PhpExcel: remove all formatting from sheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using the library PhpExcel to import data from Excel.

I would like to remove all formatting from the spreadsheet so I can ready the values with the RangeToArray function.

OR

I'd like to read a range values but it seems that rangeToArray takes into account the formatting.

How can I do ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the arguments for the `rangeToArray()` method, you'll see that it takes formatting into account **by default**

```
/**
 * Create array from a range of cells
 *
 * @param string $pRange Range of cells (i.e. "A1:B10"), or just one cell (i.e. "A1")
 * @param mixed $nullValue Value returned in the array entry if a cell doesn't exist
 * @param boolean $calculateFormulas Should formulas be calculated?
 * @param boolean $formatData Should formatting be applied to cell values?
 * @param boolean $returnCellRef False - Return a simple array of rows and columns indexed by number counting from zero
 *                               True - Return rows and columns indexed by their actual row and column IDs
 * @return array
 */
public function rangeToArray($pRange = 'A1', $nullValue = null, $calculateFormulas = true, $formatData = true, $returnCellRef = false)
```

But that you can change that behaviour simply by passing a boolean `false` as the fourth argument

Comment: arf, I was looking for so complicated things ! Thanks !